# Unable to find layout.xml in Flutter Project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I am a beginner in flutter, recently i installed flutter and dart in android studio. In android folder i can find all the necessary folders like values,main Activity.java,manifest,gradle etc, but i cannot find the layout.xml in res folder?

Answer (score 3):

Because there is no layout.xml file in Flutter, and to build UI you have to use a different structure from the native Android.
The ui structure is created in dart files.
It's a good idea to read the Flutter site documentation.
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/tutorial

Comment: is it possible to create UI in different structure from native android ? If yes, then kindly send the details or articles or videos.

Answer (score 2):

In flutter there is no such xml coding and virtual designer which is like in android studio. Instead of that you will use a different approach in flutter, all such you have to code inside your dart files by calling WIDGET classes to make such UI.